# Non uniform UV results

Tags: texturing, uv

So at the moment I am modelling a pipe wrench inspired from Bioshock. When I attempt to unwrap it I get a nonuniform shape [image: My unwrap]

Compared to the unwrap of the actual game model [image: Bioshock Wrench]

How do I get my unwrap to match that of the actual game? (Not in size but uniformity) Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

[image]

Comment: Is the scale applied? (Object mode, Ctrl+A > Scale)

Comment: Try using Smart UV Project and/or Mark some Seams and then UV Unwrap. Also, before Unwrapping, in Object Mode, Apply Scale (CTRL + "A" and select "Scale" from the drop down menu).

Comment: I have applied the scale and that's the result I got. I have also added seams (you can see were by downloading the .blend file)